# How to fix the error in GCP CommandException: "lifecycle" command spanning providers not allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lifecycle, gsutil

I am learning GCP now. I have a bucket with the name of welynx-test1_copy
I want to set a lifecycle policy to it so as the bucket would be deleted after 23 days, by following the command help I executed the following command in CLI:

```
xenonxie@cloudshell:~ (rock-perception-263016)$ gsutil ls
gs://rock-perception-263016.appspot.com/
gs://staging.rock-perception-263016.appspot.com/
gs://welynx-test1/
gs://welynx-test1_copy/
```

So you can see the bucket exists.

Setting the policy below errors me out:

```
xenonxie@cloudshell:~ (rock-perception-263016)$ gsutil lifecycle set {"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"age": 23}}]} gs://welynx-test1_copy
```

> CommandException: "lifecycle" command spanning providers not allowed.

I've tried to follow the syntax found in the `help` as below:

> xenonxie@cloudshell:~ (rock-perception-263016)$ gsutil lifecycle
>   --help NAME   lifecycle - Get or set lifecycle configuration for a bucket
>
> SYNOPSIS   gsutil lifecycle get url   gsutil lifecycle set
>   config-json-file url...
>
> DESCRIPTION   The lifecycle command can be used to get or set
>   lifecycle management policies   for the given bucket(s). This command
>   is supported for buckets only, not   objects. For more information on
>   object lifecycle management, please see the   `Google Cloud Storage
>   docs <https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle>`_.
>
> The lifecycle command has two sub-commands: GET   Gets the lifecycle
>   configuration for a given bucket. You can get the   lifecycle
>   configuration for only one bucket at a time. The output can be
>   redirected into a file, edited and then updated via the set
>   sub-command.
>
> SET   Sets the lifecycle configuration on one or more buckets. The
>   config-json-file   specified on the command line should be a path to a
>   local file containing   the lifecycle configuration JSON document.
>
> EXAMPLES   The following lifecycle configuration JSON document
>   specifies that all objects   in this bucket that are more than 365
>   days old will be deleted automatically:
>
> ```
> {
>   "rule":
>   [
>     {
>       "action": {"type": "Delete"},
>       "condition": {"age": 365}
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> The following (empty) lifecycle configuration JSON document removes
>   all   lifecycle configuration for a bucket:
>
> ```
> {}
> ```

What am I missing here and how do I fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your command is that you put the rules in the command you want to run instead of the configuration file.

The way to do it is to:

- Create a JSON file with the lifecycle configuration rules
- Use lifecycle set like this `gsutil lifecycle set [CONFIG_FILE] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

Basically, you can just put as in the example you gave:

```
{
  "rule":
  [
    {
      "action": {"type": "Delete"},
      "condition": {"age": 23}
    }
  ]
}
```

And change CONFIG_FILE with the JSON file you have created.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `gsutil` checks to see if the bucket name belongs to google *before* it checks to see if the lifecycle file exists:

```
❯ gsutil lifecycle set foo bar gs://baz
CommandException: "lifecycle" command spanning providers not allowed.

❯ gsutil lifecycle set foo gs://baz
AccessDeniedException: 403 user@domain.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to baz.

❯ gsutil lifecycle set foo gs://a-real-bucket-name
Setting lifecycle configuration on gs://a-real-bucket-name/...
ArgumentException: JSON lifecycle data could not be loaded from:
```

So if you provide anything other than a google-controlled bucket in the fifth position:

```
gsutil lifecycle set file.json THIS_ARGUMENT
```

You'll see errors relating to that problem *instead of* errors relating to the file.

This confused me as well, I think google could make some simple modifications to gsutil to make the error messages more helpful.  I've filed a bug to that effect here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147020031

Answer (score 0):

for me i have faced this issue when i tried to put the name of the bucket inside an exported variable and then tried to use in gsutil command
[running with and without variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl6Yh.png)